# Error deleting contents in directory - Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4 | Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=2 "No such file or directory"

Tags: swift, swift3, nsfilemanager

How can I fix the following errors when running the code below? I already searched in SO but can't find anything for Swift 3.

```
// Delete all files in given directory
let path = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)[0] as String
let dataPath = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: path)
if let enumerator = FileManager.default.enumerator(atPath: dataPath.path!) {
    while let fileName = enumerator.nextObject() as? String {
        do {
            try FileManager.default.removeItem(atPath: "\(dataPath)\(fileName)")
        }
        catch let e as NSError {
            print(e)
        }
        catch {
            print("error")
        }
    }
}
```

Log:

> Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4 "“.DS_Store” couldn’t be removed." UserInfo={NSFilePath=file:///Users/CIPL0469/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/F0106B28-C4D1-4FE2-A425-D04C6BFDDC01/data/Containers/Data/Application/A5AB9B7B-6174-4BA7-9EFD-0E9F1C98CB17/Documents/.DS_Store, NSUserStringVariant=(
>       Remove
>   ), NSUnderlyingError=0x60800004fed0 {Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=2 "No such file or directory"}}
>
> Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4 "“2017-01-31_10-44-21.m4a” couldn’t be removed." UserInfo={NSFilePath=file:///Users/CIPL0469/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/F0106B28-C4D1-4FE2-A425-D04C6BFDDC01/data/Containers/Data/Application/A5AB9B7B-6174-4BA7-9EFD-0E9F1C98CB17/Documents/2017-01-31_10-44-21.m4a, NSUserStringVariant=(
>       Remove
>   ), NSUnderlyingError=0x60800004fa80 {Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=2 "No such file or directory"}}
>
> Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4 "“2017-01-31_10-44-26.m4a” couldn’t be removed." UserInfo={NSFilePath=file:///Users/CIPL0469/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/F0106B28-C4D1-4FE2-A425-D04C6BFDDC01/data/Containers/Data/Application/A5AB9B7B-6174-4BA7-9EFD-0E9F1C98CB17/Documents/2017-01-31_10-44-26.m4a, NSUserStringVariant=(
>       Remove
>   ), NSUnderlyingError=0x60000004f570 {Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=2 "No such file or directory"}}

Answer (score 5):

`nextObject()` of `(NS)DirectoryEnumerator` returns always the full path / url of the enumerated items, an additional concatenation breaks the path. Aside form that concatenating `URL` and `String` with String Interpolation to pass it as `path` parameter doesn't work at all.

I recommend to use the URL related API anyway

```
let fileManager = FileManager.default
do {
    let url = try fileManager.url(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: false)
    if let enumerator = fileManager.enumerator(at: url, includingPropertiesForKeys: nil) {
        while let fileURL = enumerator.nextObject() as? URL {
            try fileManager.removeItem(at: fileURL)
        }
    }
}  catch  {
    print(error)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to make it clear:

```swift
let addr = one["resourceAddr"] as! String
do {
   try FileManager.default.removeItem(at: URL(string:addr)!)
} catch let error as NSError {
    print("error: ", error.localizedDescription)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is mostly happening because the file you are trying to read at URL does not exist.